# If I make N trials, each independent with p chance of success, what is the probability that X or more of them will be successful?

Tags: probability

In my problem, $p$, $X$, and $N$ are fixed and I want to know the probability.
Currently, I am calculating this recursively, as for any given $p$, $X$, $N$, the probability is:

```
function Prob(p,X,N) {
  return p*Prob(p,X-1,N-1) + (1-p)*Prob(p,X,N-1)
}
```

The intuition behind this is that if we were successful (first term) we have $X-1$ more successes to find and $N-1$ more trials. If we weren't successful $(1-p)$, we have $X$ more successes to find and $N-1$ more trials.
There are also base cases that I left out where $X=0$ (probability is 1 because we've gotten all the successes) and $N$ less than $X$ (probability is zero because we have no more trials)
The recursion is really killing the speed of computation, so I'm looking for a closed form or approximation or just a point in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: It is just the binomial term $_N C$$_X$ $p^X$ ($1-p$$^N$$^-$$^X$)..

Comment: ah, sorry, it wasn't clear that it's x *or more* successes. that binomial equation gives me the equation to calculate the probability of exactly X successes

Comment: Then just sum up the terms from X to N.

Comment: that is a good idea, im trying that right now

Comment: If you are using R then `1 - pbinom(X-1, N, p)` will give this efficiently and  other languages may also have built-in functions

Comment: Thanks guys for helping out, it's running a lot faster after I implemented the `1 - cdf` idea.

Comment: @Henry While algebraically correct, numerically it's better to use `pbinom` (or other `p...` functions for the cdf) with the argument `lower.tail=FALSE`, which gives probabilities in the upper tail by calculations which are accurate for the upper tail. This makes a difference when in the far upper tail (when the area in the lower tail is very close to 1). Calculation of very small upper tails by subtraction can result in a loss of many figures of accuracy. If you know the upper tail probability is not close to zero there's no issue but if it is (or even *might be*, then this approach is safer.

Comment: @Glen_b - what you say is true, but the problem I see more often is that many people seem to expect `pbinom(X, N, p, lower.tail=FALSE)` to give the right answer here when they should be using `pbinom(X-1, N, p, lower.tail=FALSE)`.  Teaching `1-pbinom(X-1, N, p)` seems to be easier for them to understand intuitively

Comment: Having just taught this sort of material again a couple of weeks ago (in a subject covering basic probability using R), I certainly agree that it's easier to teach `1-pbinom(X-1, N, p)` - especially to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most programming languages have "Cumulative Distribution Functions" (CDF) for various distributions.  As a result, you shouldn't have to individually compute each probability and then sum up to $X$.  For example, in R, to obtain the CDF of a binomial distribution with $p=.20$, $n=50$, and $X=10$, you don't need to calculate:

```
> sum(dbinom(x=0:10, size=50, prob=0.20))
[1] 0.5835594
```

Instead, you could simply use:

```
> pbinom(q=10, size=50, prob=0.20)
[1] 0.5835594
```

Comparing the times, you see that the built in CDF function is generally faster:

```
> Sys.time()->start;
> sum(dbinom(0:54, size=100, prob=.50) )
[1] 0.8158992
> print(Sys.time()-start);
Time difference of 0.002012014 secs
> 
> Sys.time()->start;
> pbinom(q=54, size=100, prob=0.50)
[1] 0.8158992
> print(Sys.time()-start);
Time difference of 0.0009989738 secs
```

Also, if $n$ is large and/or $p$ is close to 0.50, you can use a normal approximation to the binomial.  For example, suppose you wanted to calculate the Probability of at least 41 successes in 80 tries when $p=0.5$.  You could calculate:

```
n=80
x=41
p=.5
q=1-p

pbinom(n,size=n,prob=p)-pbinom(x,size=n,prob=p)
[1] 0.3687772
```

or you could use the normal approximation:

```
1-pnorm(x,mean=n*p,sd=sqrt(n*p*q))
0.4115316
```

and with continuity correction, you get:

```
1-pnorm(x+.5,mean=n*p,sd=sqrt(n*p*q))
0.3686578
```

Comment: Wow! That is much faster, thanks.  
I'm using python, so the code ended up being:  
`1 - scipy.stats.binom.cdf(X-1, Y, p)`  
I think my p's are going to very a lot so this should work for me.

Comment: Great!  Yes, most languages have CDF functions that are optimized for this so you don't have to "roll your own," which tend to be slower, in my experience.